# Как сделать переход на следующую/предыдущую страницу JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопки типа `<` и `>`,
как реализовать переход на страницы (следущая, предыдущая)
например с помощью `window.location.href`?

почему-то так не работает:

```
$('a.next').click(function() {
    window.location = $('#accordion .active2').next().find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Убедитесь что переменная `newLocation` выдает то что Вам нужно, а слушатель "повешен" на правильный элемент:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
  const newLocation = $("#accordion .active2").next().find("a").attr("href")
  location.assign(newLocation)
})
```

*Если Вы переходите на страницы за пределами Вашего домена то стоит так же обратить внимание на настройки CORS.*